# SQL Server stored procedure taking a LONG time to run after minor changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes info from two tables I created to generate a summary table that is then used with several views.

Previously this took between 60-90 seconds to run. I had two calls to functions for different costs, and a third that makes another call for cost * qty. I removed all 3 and replaced with a new function that is almost an exact copy of one of the other cost functions

I wrote this as I was working through it, so it's evolved a bit. I improved on the speed, but it's still nowhere near as fast as it was before and I'm not sure why.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost]
    (@PartID int)
RETURNS decimal(20, 4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pureID int = 0

    SET @pureID = (SELECT TOP(1) PURE_COST_ID 
                   FROM visuser.PART_COST 
                   WHERE EN_PART_ID = @partID 
                   ORDER BY EN_REV_MASTER_ID DESC, IC_WAREHOUSE_ID DESC)

    RETURN (SELECT TOP(1) (TOT_MATERIAL_N + TOT_MATERIAL_OVERHEAD_N) 
            FROM visuser.PURE_COST 
            WHERE PURE_COST_ID = @pureID 
            ORDER BY (TOT_MATERIAL_N + TOT_MATERIAL_OVERHEAD_N) DESC) 
END
```

Replaced with. I added the `WITH INLINE = OFF` after it first got stuck to rule that out. The function by itself works just fine.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost] 
    (@PartID int)
RETURNS decimal(20,4)
WITH INLINE = OFF
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pureID int = 0

    SET @pureID = (SELECT TOP(1) PURE_COST_ID 
                   FROM visuser.PART_COST 
                   WHERE EN_PART_ID = @partID 
                   ORDER BY EN_REV_MASTER_ID DESC, IC_WAREHOUSE_ID DESC)

    RETURN (SELECT TOP(1) (TOT_MATERIAL_N + TOT_MATERIAL_OVERHEAD_N + TOT_RUN_VALUE_N + TOT_FIXED_OVERHEAD_N) FROM visuser.PURE_COST WHERE PURE_COST_ID = @pureID ORDER BY (TOT_MATERIAL_N + TOT_MATERIAL_OVERHEAD_N) DESC) 
END
```

The other changes that I made was adding `[Qty] > 0 AND`  to the [Part Count] line
And replacing the string based entries for the Commondity ID to ints (which is more appropriate) as the COMMODITY_ID is a reference to the COMMODITY_CODE which is what the strings were.

I expected it to run faster, not run indefinitely.  The procedure is now taking forever to run.  I'm now on 38min and counting.  I also tried just copying the code in the procedure itself and running it and it is also taking forever, so it's something in the code itself.

The AllPartsList table has 1.04m lines, as does the bomBreakdown table.  The bomBreakdown table is far more complex and takes 40-60s to generate.  The bomSummary table will have 4,100 lines.  The AllPartsList table has appropriate indexes, bomBreakdown doesn't.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[createBOMSummary]
AS

    DECLARE @processTime int=0, @begin datetime, @end datetime

    SET @begin = SYSDATETIME()

    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.bomSummary', N'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE bomSummary

    SELECT 
        DISTINCT ap.[SourcePartID] AS [Assembly Part ID],
        p.[PART_X] AS [Assembly Part #],
        p.[DESCR_X] AS [Assembly Part Description],

        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Component Part #]) FROM [bomBreakdown] WHERE [Qty] > 0 AND [Component Part ID] IS NOT NULL AND SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID GROUP BY [SourcePartID]) AS [Part Count],
        (SELECT SUM([Qty]) FROM [bomBreakdown] WHERE [Component Part ID] IS NOT NULL AND SourcePartID = ap.[SourcePartID] GROUP BY [SourcePartID]) AS [Total # of Parts],
        ([dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost](ap.[SourcePartID])) AS [Factory Std Cost],

        COALESCE(
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ComponentPartID) 
              FROM AllPartsList apl
                LEFT JOIN visuser.EN_PART p1
                  ON p1.[EN_Part_ID] = apl.[ComponentPartID]
              WHERE 
                apl.ComponentPartID IS NOT NULL AND 
                apl.SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID  AND
                p1.Commodity_ID IN (15, 84, 85, 87, 81, 92) -- Commodity Codes: 009, 072, 073, 075, 079, 082
              GROUP BY SourcePartID
            ), 0) AS [# of Docs], --0sec

        COALESCE(
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ComponentPartID) 
        FROM AllPartsList apl
            LEFT JOIN visuser.EN_PART p1
                ON p1.[EN_Part_ID] = apl.[ComponentPartID]
        WHERE 
            apl.ComponentPartID IS NOT NULL AND 
            apl.SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID  AND
            p1.Commodity_ID IN (28)  -- Commodity Code 034
        GROUP BY SourcePartID
        ), 0) AS [# of Software], --0sec
    
        COALESCE(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM visuser.[PART_COST] 
        WHERE [STD_PO_Cost_N] > 0 AND 
            EN_PART_ID IN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT ComponentPartID FROM AllPartsList WHERE ComponentPartID IS NOT NULL AND SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID)
        ), 0) AS [# of Std Cost Items], --0sec

        COALESCE(
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ComponentPartID) 
        FROM AllPartsList apl
            LEFT JOIN visuser.EN_PART p1
                ON p1.[EN_Part_ID] = apl.[ComponentPartID]
        WHERE 
            apl.ComponentPartID IS NOT NULL AND 
            apl.SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID  AND
            p1.Commodity_ID IN (11)  -- Commodity Code: 002
        GROUP BY SourcePartID), 0
        ) AS [# of HR Devices] ,--0sec

        COALESCE(
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ComponentPartID) 
        FROM AllPartsList apl
            LEFT JOIN visuser.EN_PART p1
                ON p1.[EN_Part_ID] = apl.[ComponentPartID]
        WHERE 
            apl.ComponentPartID IS NOT NULL AND 
            apl.SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID  AND
            p1.Commodity_ID IN (5)  -- Commodity Code: 007
        GROUP BY SourcePartID), 0
        ) AS [# of 3rd Party Devices], --0sec
        
        COALESCE(
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ComponentPartID) 
        FROM AllPartsList apl
            LEFT JOIN visuser.EN_PART p1
                ON p1.[EN_Part_ID] = apl.[ComponentPartID]
        WHERE 
            apl.ComponentPartID IS NOT NULL AND 
            apl.SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID  AND
            p1.Commodity_ID IN (13) AND  -- Commodity Code: 005
            p1.MAKE_BUY_C = 'B'
        GROUP BY SourcePartID
        ), 0) AS [# of Robots], --0sec
        
        COALESCE(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM visuser.[PART_COST] c
            LEFT JOIN visuser.[EN_PART] p
            ON p.[EN_PART_ID] = c.[EN_PART_ID]
        WHERE 
            c.[STD_PO_Cost_N] > 0 AND 
            p.[MAKE_BUY_C] = 'B' AND
            c.[EN_PART_ID] IN 
               (SELECT DISTINCT ComponentPartID FROM AllPartsList WHERE ComponentPartID IS NOT NULL AND SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID)
        ), 0) AS [# of Buy Parts], --0sec
        
        COALESCE(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM visuser.[PART_COST] c
            LEFT JOIN visuser.[EN_PART] p
            ON p.[EN_PART_ID] = c.[EN_PART_ID]
        WHERE 
            c.[STD_PO_Cost_N] > 0 AND 
            p.[MAKE_BUY_C] = 'M' AND
            c.[EN_PART_ID] IN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT ComponentPartID FROM AllPartsList WHERE ComponentPartID IS NOT NULL AND SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID)
        ), 0) AS [# of Make Parts]  

    INTO bomSummary
    FROM AllPartsList ap
      LEFT JOIN visuser.EN_PART p
        ON p.[EN_Part_ID] = ap.[SourcePartID]
    ORDER BY [PART_X]

    SET @end = SYSDATETIME()
    SET @processTime = DATEDIFF(s, @begin, @end)

    PRINT @end
    PRINT CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)
    PRINT 'bomSummary Processing Time: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @processTime)

GO
```

Here's how the bomBreakdown table looks:
[image: bomBreadkdown table]

And the AllPartsList table:
[image: AllPartsList table]

If I comment out the function line two records takes 1m 20s to process, here's part of the execution plan.  It looks like each COALESCE I have adds 4-6 seconds to the process time.
[image: Execution List 1]

If I remove all the COALESCE then it takes 2min 50sec to process all 4981 records. Here's the execution list for it:
[image: Execution List 2]

The execution plans suggested a couple additional indexes, so I added those and now 1 record takes 0 seconds, 2 took 5 secs, 10 took 1 sec, 100 took 2sec, 1000 took 28, and all 4981 took 4min 17sec.
The additional indexes certainly helped, I no longer see %s over 1000%, there are several still over 100% which makes me think there is some more optimization that could be done, I'm just not sure where.  The execution plan is huge, so here just a few shots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Not sure what was up with the 2 records.  It's not the 90sec it was before, but it at least finishes now.

Odd thing I see is that it has (1000 rows affected), then (1 row affected).  I have no idea what that 1 row is or where it's coming from.  And I'd still like to know why making those few changes made such a hug difference.

I'm using:

- SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2070.41)
- SSMS v18.5

Here are the results of my modifications based on allmhuran's suggestions:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ap.[SourcePartID] AS [Assembly Part ID],
    p.[PART_X] AS [Assembly Part #],
    p.[DESCR_X] AS [Assembly Part Description],
    oa2.[Part Count],
    oa2.[Total # of Parts],
    ([dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost](ap.[SourcePartID])) AS [Factory Std Cost],
    oa2.[# of Docs],
    oa2.[# of Software],
    'Logic Pending' AS [# of Std Cost Items],
    oa2.[# of HR Devices],
    oa2.[# of 3rd Party Devices],
    oa2.[# of Robots],
    oa2.[# of Buy Parts],
    oa2.[# of Make Parts]
    
  FROM AllPartsList ap
    LEFT JOIN visuser.EN_PART p
      ON p.[EN_Part_ID] = ap.[SourcePartID]
  OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
            [Part Count]                = COUNT(    DISTINCT IIF( [Qty] = 0, null, [Component Part #])  ),  
            [Total # of Parts]          = SUM([Qty]),
            [# of Docs]                 = COUNT(    DISTINCT IIF( [Commodity Code] IN ('009', '072', '073', '075', '079', '082'), [Component Part #], null) ), -- Commodity Codes: 009, 072, 073, 075, 079, 082  :  Commodity ID: 15, 84, 85, 87, 81, 92
            [# of Software]             = COUNT(    DISTINCT IIF( [Commodity Code] IN ('034'), [Component Part #], null)    ), -- Commodity Code 034  :  Commodity ID: 28
            [# of HR Devices]           = COUNT(    DISTINCT IIF( [Commodity Code] IN ('002'), [Component Part #], null)    ), -- Commodity Code 002  :  Commodity ID: 11
            [# of 3rd Party Devices]    = COUNT(    DISTINCT IIF( [Commodity Code] IN ('007'), [Component Part #], null)    ), -- Commodity Code 007  :  Commodity ID: 5
            [# of Robots]               = COUNT(    DISTINCT IIF( ( [Commodity Code] IN ('005') AND [Make/Buy] = 'B' ), [Component Part #], null)   ), -- Commodity Code 005  :  Commodity ID: 13
            [# of Buy Parts]            = COUNT(    DISTINCT IIF( [Make/Buy] = 'B', [Component Part #], null)   ),
            [# of Make Parts]           = COUNT(    DISTINCT IIF( [Make/Buy] = 'M', [Component Part #], null)   )

          FROM bomBreakdown
          WHERE
            [Component Part ID] IS NOT NULL AND 
            [SourcePartID] = ap.[SourcePartID] AND
            --[SourcePartID] = ap.[AssemblyPartID] AND
            ap.SourcePartID = 964
          GROUP BY [SourcePartID]
    ) oa2
```

Comment: Yep :D. There's a lot of code there. Nice work putting all of the relevant info into the question, unfortunately I can't go through it all at the moment. But as a first, relatively simple refactor: turn your scalar function into an inline table valued function, and cross apply it to get the scalar value. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62873630/7165279). This may or may not be a complete solution, but it's a good first step and will almost certainly be a part of a more complete solution

Comment: One note on that - in your case, you probably want to use `outer apply` instead of `cross apply`, because with `cross apply`, if the function returns no values, that's the same as a join which returns no rows - the entire select statement will return no rows. With `outer apply`, if the function returns no rows, it works like a left join. You'll just get a null for the value of the `[Factory Std Cost]` column

Comment: @allmhuran Excellent, I wasn't sure if I could tag you if you hadn't replied to it :D  I will look into converting the function and see if I can make sense of it all :D  I learn something new every day and love it!

Comment: No worries, if you have any trouble figuring out where to put the `outer apply`, ping me again

Comment: I had a quick look over the stored procedure as a whole. This is actually a *fantastic* procedure to use as a demonstration of useful refactoring techniques, because there are multiple groups of sub-selects that use *almost* identical queries, with the difference being just one or two predicates. That means we might be able to factor them out and only run them once, saving a lot of table scans, and we just process the results of the select in a clever way based on the conditions. It's quite a lot of work, but if nobody else gets to it, I might later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, snuck in a bit of time to go through this.

**Scalar function refactor**

As mentioned in my comment, scalar functions do bad things to set based operations. In general, if you have a pattern like

```
create function scalar_UDF(@i int) returns int as begin
   return @i * 2;
end

select    c = scalar_UDF(t.c)
from      t;
```

Then this turns your select into a row-by-agonising-row (RBAR) operation under the covers.

You can improve the performance by sticking with set based operations. One way to do this is to mark the scalar UDF as `inline`, which basically tells SQL it can rewrite your query to this before generating a query plan:

```
select    c = t.c * 2
from      t;
```

But scalar function inlining is a difficult thing for microsoft to solve, and is still a bit buggy. Another way is to handle it yourself, by using an inline table valued function and `cross apply` or `outer apply`

```
create function inline_TVF(@i int) returns table as return 
(
   select result = @i * 2
)

select       c = u.result
from         t
outer apply  inline_TVF(t.c) u;
```

**Actual factorization refactor**

Part of your existing procedure looks like this:

```
select      [Part Count] =
            (
               select   count(distinct [Component Part #])
               from     bomBreakdown
               where    Qty > 0
                        and [Component Part ID] is not null
                        and SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID
               group by SourcePartID
            ),
            [Total # of Parts] =
            (
               select   sum(Qty)
               from     bomBreakdown
               where    [Component Part ID] is not null
                        and SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID
               group by SourcePartID
            )
            -- , more ...
```

Those two subqueries look really similar. It's this sort of pattern:

```
select      a = (
               select x1 from y where z
            ),
            b = (
               select x2 from y where almost_z
            )
```

What we'd really like to do is something like the following. If we could, then the query only needs to hit the `y` table once, instead of hitting it twice. But of course the syntax wouldn't be valid:

```
select      a = t.x1, 
            b = t.x2
from        (
                select  x1 where z, 
                        x2 where almost_z
                from y
            ) t
```

Aha, but perhaps we can be a bit clever. If we look back to your specific case, we might change it into something like this:

```
select      oa1.[Part Count],
            oa1.[Total # of Parts]
into        bomSummary
from        AllPartsList    ap
left join   visuser.EN_PART p   on p.EN_Part_ID = ap.SourcePartID
outer apply (
                select    [Part Count]       = count
                                               (
                                                  distinct iif
                                                  (
                                                     Qty = 0, null, [Component Part #]
                                                  )
                                               ),
                          [Total # of Parts] = sum(qty)
                from      bomBreakdown
                where     [Component Part ID] is not null
                          and SourcePartID = ap.SourcePartID
                group by  SourcePartID
            ) 
            oa1
```

Here, the `iif(Qty = 0, null, [Component Part #])` will make the column null if the quantity is zero. Count will ignore those nulls. And we get the distinct, just like before. So we have sneakily managed to get a `where` clause in here: "count the distinct `component part #` values where the quantity is not equal to zero". Now we can just sum the `Qty` column as well, and we're done refactoring this.

The same kind of refactoring can be done in *many* places in this stored procedure. It would actually be a great learning exercise for refactoring SQL. I'm not going to do all of them, but just try to identify the patterns, and follow a factorisation process - the same kind you would do in algebra. Because, in many ways, this *is* algebra!

Please excuse any typos/syntax errors. I haven't been able to check this through an actual query window, my intent here is to demonstrate a few ideas, not to actually rewrite the original query.

Comment: I posted code at the bottom of the question which is what I came up with.  I'll have to wait until tomorrow to verify.  I'm now trying to clean up a SPROC that takes 5.5hrs to run.  I think you'd cry if you saw it.

Comment: @Dizzy49 I have had to debug and optimise a 10,000 line (vendor) procedure. Or rather, recommend optimisations back to the vendor and hope they implement them. I have stared into the void, and by consequence, and at the cost of becoming the void, ascended beyond the plane of tears.

Comment: @Dizzy49 OK, I haven't verified the logical equivalence of your updated version to your original, and to be honest I probably won't - that's going to have to be a debugging exercise for you :) But if that really is the logical equivalent, then that is *so* much more comprehensible than the original. And it's probably much, much faster too. This is often true of SQL in a way that it is not always true of many languages: if elegant, then fast. If it was previously 90 seconds before any modification then I'm going to guess.... hm... maybe 10 now. Let me know how close I am.

Comment: It was 4m 15s, now it's 1m 28s, definite improvement.  Prob that function that's slowing it down.

Comment: @Dizzy49 Since so much now folds into the `apply`, you may find that rewriting the `outer apply` as a plain `left join` without any subquery at all is faster still. `Apply` is more versatile, but sometimes not quite as well optimised. Not super important. I notice you have the condition `[SourcePartID] = ap.[SourcePartID] AND ap.SourcePartID = 964`, was that just for testing? Yep, you should see another huge improvement when you take that scalar function call out of the `select`, and move it into an `outer apply`. I missed that it was still in `select` in your current refactor.

Comment: @Dizzy49 You will probably need to write a whole new function rather than change the existing one, in case it's used in other places. But what you *could* do, if you wanted, is write the new inline-table-valued version, and then change the internals of the existing scalar version so that it calls the new inline one, and assigns the output to a variable, and returns it. That way they are both guaranteed to always be logically in sync without making any breaking changes to the existing scalar function interface.

Comment: `ap.SourcePartID = 964` was used for testing and I left it in by accident :D  I'm trying to see if I can lose the function entirely and move it to an `apply`  Still tweaking the overall logic since some numbers aren't matching up, then I'll work on optimizing again.  At least now running the process isn't a day long thing!